# Azure Container Registry: I keep getting Status 401 when viewing the repositories tab

Tags: azure-container-registry

I'm new to docker. I just created a registry on the portal. However, when I try to see what's in the repositories tab, I get a **Status 401**. All the tutorial just tells how to create an ACR. That's what I did. Yet, I keep getting this error.

I'm the one who created this registry. How come I don't have access to it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try below steps?

1: Go to the container registry on the Azure Portal

2: Select Access Control(IAM).

3: Click on "Add role assignment" under "Grant access to this resources"

4: Go to "Privileged administrator roles" and select "Owner"

5: Click on "Next" at the bottom of the page.

6: Now please click on "Select Members"

7: You can add yourself (either name / email) and click on "Select" at the bottom of the right expanded pane.

8: Click on "Review and Assign"

Comment: Just came back to thank you again